# CSS overflow issue

Tags: css

I have a `div` which has the css `overflow` property set to `auto`. But the overflow property doesn't seem to work and instead of showing a scrollbar within the div, the content of div flows outside div.

What am I missing here?

```
<div id="divPrvChatBox">
</div>

#divPrvChatBox
{
    width:330px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:Yellow;
    overflow:auto;        
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results. For example, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/8SNKz/ The content does not flow outside the div for me. What OS/browser/version are you using, and can you paste a reproducible test case and screenshot?

Comment: I am opening the window like this..window.open("ChatWindow.aspx?username=" + toUsername,'_blank', "scrollbars=1,width=340,height=200");

Comment: OK it worked when I did an inline styling with overflow:auto...but not with ID css attribute

Comment: It should work via CSS as well. If you can provide an exact example showing your problem, we can help fix it properly. How you are opening the window is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
overflow:scroll;
```

This is what you need to explicitly tell the browser to use scroll-bars. When you use `auto` you are telling the browser that it can decide for itself, often giving some WTF results.

Comment: Yes, and auto is the default setting, so that's just the same as not setting it at all.

Comment: @Nathan `auto` is not the default setting. The default is [`visible`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-overflow).

Comment: @rlb.usa I don't know what you mean by 'wtf' results, but `overflow:scroll` will force scrollbars to always appear, while `overflow:auto` will cause them to only appear when needed. What the OP is using is usually what is desired, and appears to be what is desired in this case, and also works.

Answer (score 1):

Set overflow to scroll:

```
#divPrvChatBox
{
    width:330px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:Yellow;
    overflow: scroll;        
}
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/JgF69/).

Comment: Downvoted because this forces scrollbars to always appear, and would not do anything additional to solve what the OP reports as a problem (content overflowing the container) beyond what `auto` already does.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that (for whatever reason) your `overflow` CSS style is not being applied. Perhaps you have a syntax error in your CSS. Perhaps your setting is being overridden. As noted in my comment above and shown in [this simple test case](http://jsfiddle.net/8SNKz/) using `overflow:auto` *does* prevent content from drawing outside the borders of the container, and also causes scrollbars to appear as needed.

Use the Developer Tools for your browser (F12 for IE, right-click and Inspect Element for Chrome or Safari, install Firebug for Firefox) to inspect the actual styles applied to the element in question. You will either see that your rule is not being applied, of the property is not part of your rule, or the rule is being overridden by a more specific selector.